# Is it possible to use Symfony2 web profiler bundle with Zend Framework 1 or other framework?

Tags: zend-framework, symfony

I have existing project written in *Zend Framework 1*, it is long term project, constantly developed and without possibility of migrating to *ZF2*. It would be really neat to use *Symfony2 Web Profiler* bundle in it.

Currently, in development, I am using zfdebug (https://packagist.org/packages/spekkionu/zfdebug) which is great, but bundle from Symfony2 has so much more to offer...

I managed to incorporate Composer into my application (in Bootstrap), so loading something with it should be no problem. Also I found package on Packgaist (https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/web-profiler-bundle) but to be honest - I don't know if it is even usable without Symfony2.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is not possible. If you take a look at the requirements on packagist you see it requires `symfony/http-kernel`, `symfony/routing` and `symfony/twig-bridge` to work. That's because the way the WebProfilerBundle works:

It registers himself at the most common events, the events happening in the HttpKernel and Routing component. If he cannot register to these events, he will not be able to give you timer information.

Moreover, it uses another event to inject imself in your page, meaning that if you don't have that event, you will never see the bar.

And the bundle is using Symfony conventions and techniques, meaning that it cannot run on ZF conventions and techniques. This is why it is called a Bundle instead of a Component, components are stand alone, bundles aren't.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. This certainly explains everything.  I am new to Symfony and I didn't really knew difference between bundle and component.